# How do I install an old app on a new phone?

Tags: ios, itunes, applications

I recently purchased an iPhone 6, and I used to use an iPhone 4.  I have several apps on my old phone that I'd like to bring onto my new phone.  I've backed up these apps into my iTunes, and I'd like to install them from my iTunes onto the new iPhone.

My problem is that, when I try to install the apps onto my new iPhone, it won't let me do so without deleting all of the existing data on the new phone.  I've been using the new phone in the interim, so I've got a bunch of stuff on it that I'd rather not lose.

How can I install these older apps onto my newer phone without losing everything?

Comment: Try [iFunbox](http://www.i-funbox.com/).

Comment: @AndrewLarsson That program has helped out with some of my issues, but I haven't been able to figure out a way to get app data (saved games and such) to transfer.  If you expanded that comment into an answer and described how to get appdata over, I'd likely accept it.

Comment: in some cases the only place of preferences and app data for an iPhone application is the `Document` or `Library` folder inside the installed folder of the app. you can use iFunbox to copy the folders from your old iPhone to your computer; and then to copy them back into your new iPhone using iFunbox.

Comment: The problem is that iOS 8.3+ (I've got 9.1) don't allow you to modify files inside the app's folder using iFunbox.  I've tried to do exactly what you described, but my iOS version won't allow it.